# java.lang.String cannot be cast to CustomObj

Tags: java, android

i have a custom adapter for a listview which receives an array of a custom object "CustomObj" and display it in the listview,

```
ArrayList<CustomObj> items;
```

trying to use AdapterView.OnItemClickListener:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            CustomObj obj = (CustomObj)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
        }
    };
```

**or**

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            CustomObj obj = (CustomObj)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        }
    };
```

Causes the Error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.project1.CustomObj
```

Comment: it is telling you that `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)` is a String and cannot be type cast into CustomObj

Comment: the error seems self-explanatory as mkjh already said. maybe you can map a String to a CustomObj, but you can't cast it.

Comment: which is more confusing , because when i try to assign it to a string like:
String stg = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

shows me an error:

Required type:
String
Provided:
Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're trying to use

```
arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
```

will return the item at the `arg2` position in the dataset.

Now what exactly is your data set? You might have used this somewhere

```
adapterView.setAdapter(YOUR_ADAPTER)
```

This is how you set an adapter to your adapter view. The `adapter` provides the data for your view.
Now if you go to the `YOUR_ADAPTER` class, you'll find a method:

```
public Object getItem(int i) {
```

The values this method is returning, are the ones you'll get on the item click event `arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);`.

In your case, it seems like the `getItem` returns a string, so you can't cast it to `CustomObj`.

Comment: yes indeed, my getItem(int i) was returning items.get(i).toString();

which was causing this problem and i could notice due to how long my code is.

i feel so stupid ...